# jQuery dropdown only stylizes once, upon refresh its normal dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Trying to achieve the "drop down" effect I have on my form here once you click "add mileage and open it that is"

it seems to only happen upon the first load, if you refresh or go back to the page at anytime the damn thing turns into an ugly normal non jquery drop down. im assuming its because im using javascript to populate my select (drop down). Any help would be appreciated....`

.js

```
// Create select element with options.
function makeRunRecord() {
    var formTag = document.getElementsByTagName('form'),
    selectList = ge('select'),
    makeSelect = document.createElement('select');
    makeSelect.setAttribute("id", "styles");
    makeSelect.setAttribute("name", "styles");
    makeSelect.setAttribute("class", "required select");
    makeSelect.setAttribute("data-native-menu", "false");
    var makePlace = document.createElement('option');
    makePlace.setAttribute("data-placeholder", "true");
    makePlace.setAttribute("value", "");
    makeSelect.appendChild(makePlace);
    for (var i=0, j=runningStyles.length; i<j; i++) {
        var makeOption = document.createElement('option');
        var optText = runningStyles[i];
        makeOption.setAttribute("value", optText);
        makeOption.innerHTML = optText;
        makeSelect.appendChild(makeOption);
    }
    selectList.appendChild(makeSelect);
};   
// Call Functions
makeRunRecord();    
});
```

.html

```
<li><div id="select"><label for="rStyle">Choose Run Style*</label></div>
```

Comment: You need to narrow down the area of your code that's giving you an issue. No one can really help with this. It appears you're mixing jQuery with regular DOM calls. Start by making everything jQuery and go from there.

Comment: Done, maybe that will help out.

Comment: All fixed help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery standard dropdown only stylizing on page load, hit refresh and its the ugly normal one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109488/jquery-standard-dropdown-only-stylizing-on-page-load-hit-refresh-and-its-the-ug). Please don't ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to execute `makeRunRecord()` before jQuery Mobile has finished enhancing the page.  To execute code right after jqm has finished enhancing use the [`pageinit` event](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html).

It will look something like this:

```
$( '#additem' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  makeRunRecord();
});
```