# jQuery standard dropdown only stylizing on page load, hit refresh and its the ugly normal one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Trying to achieve the "drop down" effect I have on my form here once you click "add mileage and open it that is"

it seems to only happen upon the first load, if you refresh or go back to the page at anytime the damn thing turns into an ugly normal non jquery drop down. im assuming its because im using javascript to populate my select (drop down). Any help would be appreciated....`

.js

```
// Create select element with options.
function makeRunRecord() {
    var formTag = document.getElementsByTagName('form'),
        selectList = ge('select'),
        makeSelect = document.createElement('select');
        makeSelect.setAttribute("id", "styles");
    makeSelect.setAttribute("name", "styles");
        makeSelect.setAttribute("class", "required select");
        makeSelect.setAttribute("data-native-menu", "false");
        var makePlace = document.createElement('option');
    makePlace.setAttribute("data-placeholder", "true");
    makePlace.setAttribute("value", "");
    makeSelect.appendChild(makePlace);
    for (var i=0, j=runningStyles.length; i<j; i++) {
        var makeOption = document.createElement('option');
        var optText = runningStyles[i];
        makeOption.setAttribute("value", optText);
        makeOption.innerHTML = optText;
        makeSelect.appendChild(makeOption);
    }
    selectList.appendChild(makeSelect);
};


// Call Functions
```

makeRunRecord();

});
.html

```
                   <li><div id="select"><label for="rStyle">Choose Run Style*</label></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the function after the page has loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
    makeRunRecord();
}
```

Comment: Still no luck. :( Should I try adding that at the top of my HTML instead, maybe in the header? So it loads first thing

Comment: you onload might not be the best time, try `document.onready` instead.

Comment: I fixed it I believe, I removed window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { that was wrapped around my whole code, and also added this to the top...    $("#additem").on("pagecreate", function(){
    makeRunRecord();
 }); not sure if its gonna cause problems down the road  but it works now! However if anyone knows why this fixed it please explain!

Comment: Wrapped in `window.onload = function(){...}`, it shouldn't matter where the statement lies in the document. Are you sure the function runs without error on all occasions?

Comment: I didn't end up using window.onload function , i used $("#additem").on("pagecreate", function(){ makeRunRecord(); });

Comment: Helter, are you saying that ` $("#additem").on("pagecreate" ...)` worked?

Comment: No i think getting rid of the DOM contentloaded is what fixed it but yes that function works

Comment: That's kewl. Good luck with the rest of your dev.